# MYSQL Grouping by each word in phrases to count/Quantify ratio

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MYSQL/MariaDB table with data like this:

```
language      phrase              tries   success
-----------   ---------------     -----   -------
Spanish       hola como estas       5        3
Spanish       como estas tu         3        1
Spanish       adios me voy          2        0
Spanish       adios me voy          1        0
Spanish       adios me voy          2        1
Spanish       como voy              3        2
English       hello how are you     5        2
English       hello who are you     3        0
English       how good are you      5        1
English       be good               3        3
French        au revoir             4        0
French        merci beaucoup        2        1
French        merci beaucoup        5        2
French        beaucoup des choses   2        2
French        voir et revoir        3        2
```

I would like to group per language and per each word contained in the phrases to quantify the "success" of each word by summing the number of tries and the number of successes and then calculating a ratio between them, so for example, in "Spanish", the word "como" appears in 3 rows, summing 11 tries and 6 succeses, so the "ratio" for "como" in Spanish would be 0.54 and do this for each word so I would end with something like this:

```
language   word    tries  successes  ratio
--------   ------  -----  ---------  -----
spanish    hola      5        3       0.60
spanish    como     11        6       0.54
spanish    estas     8        4       0.54
spanish    tu        3        1       0.33
spanish    adios     5        1       0.20
spanish    me        5        1       0.20
spanish    voy       8        3       0.38
english    hello     8        2       0.25
english    how       10       3       0.30
english    are       13       3       0.23
english    you       13       3       0.23
english    who       3        0       0
english    good      8        4       0.54
english    be        3        3       1
french     au        4        0       0
french     revoir    7        2       0.29
french     merci     7        3       0.43
french     beaucoup  9        5       0.55
french     des       2        2       1
french     choses    2        2       1 
french     voir      3        2       0.66
french     et        3        2       0.66
```

I am at a loss on how to accomplish this in SQL.

FYI the real table contains about 50,000 rows and phrases can havee from 1 to 7 words, being 2-4 words the most common

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Splitting the phrases into words needs to be done in application code.  Once you have done that, you may want to the math there, too.  Or you can present the revised schema for discussing how to do the math.

Comment: Purely query based solution would require a sequence table and complex string operations, and will be time consuming for large tables. So, as Rick suggested, it is better to fix the schema and application code. Now, still if you want SQL based solution, you need to tell us: what is the Primary key in this table ?

Comment: Thank you all that have chimed in. @GMB version is 10.2.26-MariaDB. This is a single table development database where I have dumped data from a big .csv. I set the primary key to the combination of the 3 fields that I know no row will have them the same, so 'Phrase', 'Language' and 'Date'(sorry I had omitted the Date column in the example to simplify).

Comment: @dodecafonico and those who asked about the primary key. It is perfectly fine to have such a table without a primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must iterate through the strings' words first. You do this with a recursive query in SQL. The rest is aggregation.

```
with recursive words (language, word, tries, success, rest) as
(
  select
    language,
    substring_index(concat(trim(phrase), ' '), ' ', 1) as word,
    tries,
    success,
    substring(trim(phrase), instr(concat(trim(phrase), ' '), ' ') + 1) as rest
  from mytable
  union all
  select
    language,
    substring_index(concat(rest, ' '), ' ', 1) as word,
    tries,
    success,
    substring(rest, instr(concat(rest, ' '), ' ') + 1) as rest
  from words
  where rest <> ''
)
select
  language,
  word,
  sum(tries) as sum_tries,
  sum(success) as sum_success,
  sum(success) / sum(tries) as ratio
from words
group by language, word
order by language, word;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=dd68b85cc7478697edebd0a9abd5b87f

Here is recursive queries in MariaDB explained: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/

Comment: brilliant, thank you so much. I didn't know about recursive queries, now I do :)

Answer (score 3):

### Solution #1: Sequence Storage Engine

Newer MariaDB versions have the build in [*Sequence Storage Engine*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/). E.g. the (virtual) table `seq_1_to_1000` contains sequence numbers from 1 to 1000. This can be utilized to split the phrases into rows per word. Consider the following query:

```
select
  t.*,
  s.seq,
  substring_index(substring_index(t.phrase, ' ', s.seq), ' ', -1) as word
from tbl t
join seq_1_to_1000 s
  on s.seq <= char_length(t.phrase) -  char_length(replace(t.phrase, ' ', '')) + 1
```

`char_length(t.phrase) -  char_length(replace(t.phrase, ' ', '')) + 1` will give us the number of words in the phrase. So we join as many rows from the sequence table as there are words in the phrase. `s.seq` column can now be used as position of a word in a phrase, and `substring_index(substring_index(t.phrase, ' ', s.seq), ' ', -1)` will extract this word. The first two rows from the original table will be transformed to

```
language   phrase            tries   success   seq   word 
--------   ---------------   -----   -------   ---   -----
Spanish    hola como estas     5        3       1    hola 
Spanish    hola como estas     5        3       2    como 
Spanish    hola como estas     5        3       3    estas
Spanish    como estas tu       3        1       1    como 
Spanish    como estas tu       3        1       2    estas
Spanish    como estas tu       3        1       3    tu
```

Now, having one row per word, we just need to group by language and word and calculate the sums:

```
select
  t.language,
  substring_index(substring_index(t.phrase, ' ', s.seq), ' ', -1) as word,
  sum(t.tries) as tries,
  sum(t.success) as success,
  sum(t.success) / sum(t.tries) as ratio
from tbl t
join seq_1_to_1000 s
  on s.seq <= char_length(t.phrase) -  char_length(replace(t.phrase, ' ', '')) + 1
group by t.language, word
```

Final result:

```
language   word       tries   success   ratio
--------   --------   -----   -------   ------
English    are         13        3      0.2308
English    be           3        3      1     
English    good         8        4      0.5   
English    hello        8        2      0.25  
English    how         10        3      0.3   
English    who          3        0      0     
English    you         13        3      0.2308
French     au           4        0      0     
French     beaucoup     9        5      0.5556
French     choses       2        2      1     
French     des          2        2      1     
French     et           3        2      0.6667
French     merci        7        3      0.4286
French     revoir       7        2      0.2857
French     voir         3        2      0.6667
Spanish    adios        5        1      0.2   
Spanish    como        11        6      0.5455
Spanish    estas        8        4      0.5   
Spanish    hola         5        3      0.6   
Spanish    me           5        1      0.2   
Spanish    tu           3        1      0.3333
Spanish    voy          8        3      0.375
```

See demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=4d91c0b12cb0cf91f294923739da1bb0)

#### Limitations

- This is a MariaDB-only solution. For oracles MySQL you would need to create a persistent sequence table or generate it "inline" with a recursive CTE.
- `seq_1_to_1000` will only work up to 1000 words per phrase. However, if you can have more, just increase the number. If in doubt, use `seq_1_to_1000000000000000`, which will be enough for 1000TB strings. Note: Since it's not a real table, only sequence numbers that are needed will be generated due to the ON clause.
- All phrases must have the same format: `<word>[(<space><word>)*]`.

### Solution #2: Recursive CTE

We can also use a *recursive CTE* (supported since MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 8.0) to split the phrases into words. Consider the following:

```
with recursive rcte as (
  select language, phrase, tries, success, 1 as pos
  from tbl t
  union all
  select language, phrase, tries, success, pos + 1
  from rcte
  where pos <= char_length(phrase) -  char_length(replace(phrase, ' ', ''))
)
select *
from rcte
order by language, phrase, pos
```

We start with position 1 (`1 as pos`) and increase it by 1 (`pos + 1`) in every recursion. This is reapeated until the position reaches the number of words (`where pos <= char_length(phrase) -  char_length(replace(phrase, ' ', ''))`). This way we "duplicate" every phrase as many times as there are words in it, having an additional column `pos` with sequence numbers.

Example of the result for two phrases:

```
language   phrase               tries   success  pos
--------   ------------------   -----   -------  ---
English    be good                3        3      1 
English    be good                3        3      2 
English    hello how are you      5        2      1 
English    hello how are you      5        2      2 
English    hello how are you      5        2      3 
English    hello how are you      5        2      4
```

We can now use the same word extraction technique as in *Solution #1*:

```
with recursive rcte as (
  select language, phrase, tries, success, 1 as pos
  from tbl t
  union all
  select language, phrase, tries, success, pos + 1
  from rcte
  where pos <= char_length(phrase) -  char_length(replace(phrase, ' ', ''))
)
select
  language,
  substring_index(substring_index(phrase, ' ', pos), ' ', -1) as word,
  sum(tries) as tries,
  sum(success) as success,
  sum(success) / sum(tries) as ratio
from rcte
group by language, word
```

Demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=3ab5b01e1061155512c16f7e96423766)